# RestAssured Ignore NoParameterValue exception when param variables are not mentioned in the url

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have defined a global `RequestSpecification` with some `pathParams` and using the spec in all requests. But not all the params used in the global spec would be used in requests. 
Assume I have mentioned 3 in the globalSpec and in some requests I would only be needing 2 params and in some 1 and in some 0 params.

But Rest-Assured is throwing `NoParameterValue` exception

```
Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 2. Redundant path parameters are: customerOrderId=io.restassured.internal.NoParameterValue@753b84c6.
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 2. Redundant path parameters are

Is there any inbuilt config/ignore mechanism that I can use to make rest-assured not throw exceptions?

**Sample Code**

```
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class TestRestAssuredParams {


    private RequestSpecification defaultRequestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .addPathParams(
                    "env", "value1",
                    "customer", "value2",
                    "order", "value3"
            )
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .build();


    private void reqWithNoParam() {
        given()
                .spec(defaultRequestSpec)
                .get("https://www.testapi.com/dev");

    }

    private void reqWith1Param() {
        given()
                .spec(defaultRequestSpec)
                .get("https://www.testapi.com/{env}");
    }

    private void reqWith2Param() {
        given()
                .spec(defaultRequestSpec)
                .get("https://www.testapi.com/{env}/{customer}");
    }

    private void reqWith3Param() {
        given()
                .spec(defaultRequestSpec)
                .get("https://www.testapi.com/{env}/{customer}/order/{order}");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestRestAssuredParams testRestAssuredParams = new TestRestAssuredParams();
        testRestAssuredParams.reqWithNoParam();
        testRestAssuredParams.reqWith1Param();
        testRestAssuredParams.reqWith2Param();
        testRestAssuredParams.reqWith3Param();
    }

}
```

How to make sure RestAssured handle the above scenario.

RestAssured version - `4.3.0`

Java - `11.0.5`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the `removeParam` of [FilterableRequestSpecification](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/specification/FilterableRequestSpecification.html),

```
private void reqWithNoParam() {
    given().filter((requestSpec, responseSpec, ctx) -> {
        requestSpec.removePathParam("env");
        requestSpec.removePathParam("customer");
        requestSpec.removePathParam("order");
        return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
    }).spec(defaultRequestSpec).log().all().get("https://www.testapi.com/dev");

}

private void reqWith1Param() {
    given().filter((requestSpec, responseSpec, ctx) -> {
        requestSpec.removePathParam("customer");
        requestSpec.removePathParam("order");
        return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
    }).spec(defaultRequestSpec).log().all().get("https://www.testapi.com/{env}");
}

private void reqWith2Param() {
    given().filter((requestSpec, responseSpec, ctx) -> {
        requestSpec.removePathParam("order");
        return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
    }).spec(defaultRequestSpec).log().all().get("https://www.testapi.com/{env}/{customer}");
}

private void reqWith3Param() {
    given().spec(defaultRequestSpec).log().all().get("https://www.testapi.com/{env}/{customer}/order/{order}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`removePathParam` in the filter does the trick.

`FilterableRequestSpecification` has a methond `getPathParamPlaceholders` which will give the params from the url mapped in the request. I removed the unneeded pathParams using that.

```
private RequestSpecification defaultRequestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .addPathParams(
                    "env", "value1",
                    "customer", "value2",
                    "order", "value3"
            )
            .addFilter((requestSpec, responseSpec, ctx) -> {
                var paramsFromRequest = requestSpec.getPathParamPlaceholders();
                var finalRequestSpec = requestSpec;
                finalRequestSpec
                        .getPathParams()
                        .forEach((key, val) -> {
                            if (!paramsFromRequest.contains(key)) {
                                finalRequestSpec.removePathParam(key);
                            }
                        });
                return ctx.next(finalRequestSpec, responseSpec);
            })
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .build();
```

Comment: I missed seeing `getPathParamPlaceholders` in the doc, thanks